# Formatting date using PHP strtotime

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I've got the following code that I am using to extract the day into a $day variable. However, PHP seems to be using the default config date format and is assuming the date format as d-m-Y. Here is my code:

```
$dateformat = "m-d-Y";
$selected_date = "04-30-2013";

$day = date(d, strtotime($selected_date));

echo $day;
```

Is there a way for me to dynamically make PHP execute based on the format defined in the $dateformat variable?

Thanks

Comment: `date(d, ` raise probably a warning. you may want to replace `d` by `$dateformat` ?

Comment: If you just want the day you need `$day = date('d', strtotime($selected_date));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `strtotime()` cannot parse date strings in custom formats. From the [documentation for `strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) (emphasis mine):

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas **if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed.**
>   To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (YYYY-MM-DD) dates or `DateTime::createFromFormat()` when possible.

The solution is to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). It can parse a date with custom format:

```
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat($dateformat, $selected_date);
$day = $dateObj->format('d'); // => 30
```

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what i'm looking for

Comment: @JohnSmith: Glad to have been of help!